# Maven with Gauge missing foledrs in intelliJ IDE

Tags: java, maven, gauge

I am following the same steps from lambda test to create a test using gauge and maven in Intellij IDE:

Navigate to File and select New Project.
Project Type as maven should be selected.
You need to select the below-mentioned name:
“com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven:gauge-maven-plugin”

This would help you to generate an archetype.
If you don’t see the archetype mentioned above, add Archetype by entering the below info.
GroupId: “com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven:
ArtifactId: “gauge-archetype-java”
After selecting the archetype, you need to click on next.

By doing so, you will be providing the Artifact ID & GroupID for your respective maven project.
GroupId: com.thoughtworks.gauge.maven
ArtifactId: GoogleSearchProject
Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT

I followed the exact same steps, but the created folder doesn't show any folders like src/test/java, .guage etc. but just pom.xml, and iml, ipr and iws files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the version number I gave.

Enter Version: 1.0.1 or the `latest version number from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/gauge/maven/gauge-archetype-java/

This solved my issue

Reference: https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin